# Logs for sql queries executed thru Spark

Tags: apache-spark, hive

I wanted to analyze sql queries executed by users from spark. I checked spark history server logs. And seems like it logs only info partially. For example when I run select statements. But doesnt log statements like create, drop or for example when I do INSERT INTO TABLE SELECT....., then it just logs the select statement. But doesnt say to which table the data was inserted. I am wondering if there is something wrong in my logs settings or this is correct behaviour. If yes, do you know what would be the best way to get historical data of queries running thru spark.

Thanks

Comment: Check the spark web UI running on port 404X of the master. It should have all the executor logs.

Comment: As mentioned earlier, it doesn't have logs for insert, create, drop, etc.. statements. Only when I do actions with the dataframe.

Comment: Does setting log level to "ALL" help?

Comment: @maverik, nope didn't help. Basically, I don't see tables in logs for which I do CREATE TABLE AS SELECT or INSERT. I just see tables from SELECT statement, but don't see tables where I am inserting the data. I can see them when I do an explain plan from spark. But they are missing in logs.